# Occasional response headers in C# HTTP Request

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

**Request:**

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
String responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(responseString);
```

**Response:**

```
{"code":"SUCCESS","details": 
    {"created_time":"","id":"xxxx"},  
    "message":"uploaded", 
    "status":"success"}
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Date: Wed, 18 Dec 2019 11:42:26 IST
Last-Modified: Wed, 18 Dec 2019 11:42:25 IST
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: Keep-Alive
Server: AWServer
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: 1
```

Whenever the above-mentioned C# request is executed, the response occasionally contains headers(HTTP/1.1 200 OK...), When I'm only trying to get the body part({"code"....} alone(response.GetResponseStream()). Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by "occasionally" and "headers"?

Comment: occasionally in the sense not all the time.I'm getting the "headers"(Date,Last-modified etc.) only in few of the same requests .

Comment: if you need headers like Date and LastModified you can try, Request.Headers.Get("Date")
HttpWebResponse. LastModified

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the basic article on http headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)

> HTTP headers let the client and the server pass additional information with an HTTP request or response. An HTTP header consists of its case-insensitive name followed by a colon (:), then by its value. Whitespace before the value is ignored.

Headers are additional information. I guess that since you left out the url and the whole creation of the Request and the url, this means that some responses have `Headers` and some not. That depends on the additional non-body information the api or web server wants to respond with.

It's in the control of the responder and not the receiver.

**Don't ignore them**: Some times interesting metadata come from Headers. It should not be `data` but information about it, like encoding, CORS info etc.

[last modified header link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified)
[date header link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Date)

Comment: Have updated the question for clarification. ```response.GetResponseStream() ```is only supposed to return the response body ,right? why is the headers being included in the body?